# Full control over HTTP headers in Python?

Tags: python, http, http-headers

Is there any Python HTTP library that helps to imitate one of popular web-browser and has HTTPS support? I would like to define the order of HTTP headers, the presence of each exact header, the order of cookies values - everything that relates to "fingerprint" of a browser. We need that to test specific web server.

Comment: For httplib, if you don't add headers, will the header contains anything you don't want?

Answer (score 2):

`httplib.request` will take an `OrderedDict` for headers. Some headers will be added automatically for protocol compliance, which will be left out if you specify them in your supplied headers.

Take a look at the `putheader` and `_send_request` methods, which you could override if their behaviour didn't suit your purposes.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> h = OrderedDict(('X-A','a'),('X-B','b'),('X-C','c'))
>>> c = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost')
>>> c.set_debuglevel(1)
>>> r = c.request('GET','/','',h)
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nX-A: a\r\nX-B: b\r\nX-C: c\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: `httplib` also has some `HTTPS` support.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which is very easy to work with and has all you need.
Alternatively you can *drive* web browser itself from Python using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: One of your link seems to be from your local network. Well, at least I cannot access.